# How to create a list of available currencies in Kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, currency

I want to create a list of pairs of currently used currencies and their corresponding display name. If possible, I would like to reduce a little bit (more to that in the following).

I have tried using Currency.getAvailableCurrencies() but it returns currencies that are not in use anymore. The best solution I have now is using Locale.getAvailableLocales() and getting the currencies from there (see following code).

I am using SortedSet to remove dublicates (which there are plenty of in the locale list) and to have it sorted.
The pair consists of the display name and the currency symbol.

```
val filteredListOfCurrencies: SortedSet<Pair<String?,String?>> = listOfLocale.map{Currency.getInstance(it)?.displayName to Currency.getInstance(it)?.symbol}.toSortedSet(
            compareBy{it.first})
```

My questions are:
1) Is there a better way to do this?
2) Is there a way to reduce the list (currently >150 currencies)

The list will be used for a cost tracking app. The standard is that NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() will be used, meaning the pre-set currency will be the device's one but I want to give the user to be able to change his currency (and also switch to "device currency").
Therefore "minor currency" will most likely be covered by the "device currency", so, if possible, I would like to reduce the list to a way shorter one, otherwise it might be a too big of a list and therefore bad user experience.

Comment: Did you find a good approach in the end. I have the same issue atm

Comment: I have pushed this issue back and havent found a solution yet, I will work on it most likely this weekend, will keep you updated!

Answer (score 1):

instead of Currency.getAvailableCurrencies(), you can pass the Locale and a date in to retrieve the valid currency codes

```
getAvailableCurrencyCodes 
public static String[] getAvailableCurrencyCodes (ULocale loc, 
                Date d)
```

where

```
loc ULocale: the locale for which to retrieve currency codes.
d   Date: the date for which to retrieve currency codes for the given locale.
```

just pass in the locale, and the date, and it'll return to you the valid currency codes.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/Currency.html#getAvailableCurrencyCodes(android.icu.util.ULocale,%20java.util.Date)

Comment: unfortunately, this will only return the available currencies for the given locale.